# search a string within a list of lists

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list with lists of strings:

```
cloud = [['SCT015, SCT040'], ['FEW015, SCT025'], ['FEW015, SCT045'],['FEW020, FEW040'], ['FEW010, FEW020, FEW040'], ['FEW012, FEW020, FEW040']],
```

and I would like to remove any instances of 'FEW' to return something like:

```
cleanCloud = [['SCT015, SCT040'], ['SCT025'], ['SCT045'], [], [], []]
```

I've tried an if statement such as:

```
cleanCloud = []

for i in cloud:
    if i[0][:3] == 'FEW':
        cleanCloud.append(i[0][8:])
    elif i[0][:3] == 'SCT':
```

But I just seem to get "lost" with the for loop. Perhaps a regex may work better but I'm having trouble thinking of how I would search and remove.

Comment: How did you get `'SCT045'` twice?

Comment: Sorry. Fixed the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need regex with a list comprehension.

```
import re
cloud = [['SCT015, SCT040'], ['FEW015, SCT025'], ['FEW015, SCT045'],['FEW020, FEW040'], ['FEW010 FEW020, FEW040'], ['FEW012, FEW020, FEW040']]

print( [re.findall(r"\bSCT\d{3}\b", j) for i in cloud for j in i] )
```

**Output:**

```
[['SCT015', 'SCT040'], ['SCT025'], ['SCT045'], [], [], []]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
cloud = [['SCT015, SCT040'], ['FEW015, SCT025'], ['FEW015, SCT045'], ['FEW020, FEW040'], ['FEW010, FEW020, FEW040'], ['FEW012, FEW020, FEW040']],

output_cloud = []
for single_element in cloud[0]:
    data = (single_element[0]).split(", ")
    output_data = []
    for sigle_data in data:
        if "FEW" not in sigle_data:
            output_data.append(sigle_data)

    output_string = ", ".join(output_data)
    print(output_string)

    output_cloud.append([output_string])

print(output_cloud)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler code without using re

```
cleanCloud = []
for inner_list in cloud:
    new_inner_list = []
    for item in inner_list:
        if 'FEW' not in item:
            new_inner_list.append(item)
    cleanCloud.append(new_inner_list)
 print(cleanCloud)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it just like:

```
cloud = [['SCT015, SCT040'], ['FEW015, SCT025'], ['FEW015, SCT045'],['FEW020, FEW040'], ['FEW010, FEW020, FEW040'], ['FEW012, FEW020, FEW040']]

for i in range(len(cloud)):
    cloud[i] = [", ".join(filter(lambda x:  'FEW' not in x, cloud[i][0].split(', ')))]
    cloud[i] = cloud[i] if cloud[i] != [''] else []

print (cloud)
```

output:

```
[['SCT015, SCT040'], ['SCT025'], ['SCT045'], [], [], []]
```